# Oracle Analytics inside Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, analytics

I'm wondering why my "analytics" line inside a "cursor" in Oracle Forms generates an error.  This is how it's written:

```
CURSOR READ_C1_REC IS  
   SELECT  DISTINCT MACH, TCODE,   
     COUNT(ALL TRANS_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY MACH, 
     TCODE ORDER BY MACH, TCODE) TOTALPERMACHPERTCODE  
   FROM  
   (
     SELECT ....
    )  
    ORDER BY MACH, TCODE;  
C1_REC READ_C1_REC%ROWTYPE;
```

...and this is the error message during compilation:

```
Error 103 at line 17, column 29
  Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

    , from
```

..and the error points to the part after the word "OVER" in the analytics.

What could be wrong with my code? Is analytics allowed inside a "cursor"?

:)

Comment: Yes it is allowed unless you use Oracle 8. What oracle release do you use?

Comment: Oh I see, you are in Oracle forms. Not server side PL/SQL. Maybe you can define a view and select from that view?

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for the suggestion.  With regards to creating a "view", I don't have the priviledge of making one.  In that case, is there any other possible solution?  :)

Comment: You are sure it is a correct syntax? Does the select-satement run in SQL PLUS?

Comment: Why don't you have the privilege to create a view? Talk to your DBA. You should have your own development database with a high level of privileges. Views don't kill toddlers.

Comment: Yes the same statement runs in Toad...with results.

Comment: "Why don't you have the privilege to create a view? Talk to your DBA. You should have your own development database with a high level of privileges. Views don't kill toddlers" - Haha thanks for the tip, but that's just the way it is, for now.

Comment: No, no, no, don't say "that's just the way it is", make same noise and talk to your boss.

Comment: +1 for using a view. Another option is to upgrade Forms - I'm pretty sure Forms 10 supports analytics.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, fyi, I tried using Oracle Forms 11g (I installed Oracle Fusion Middleware) now and it still flags the same error.  Maybe I'm looking at the wrong problem, just maybe. Any other idea of the cause of the error is very much welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Forms has (or at least did at one time) its own PL/SQL engine, and this generally lags behind the database product in terms of the features it supports.  It may be that your version of Forms has a PL/SQL engine that pre-dates the introduction of analytic functions.

You have said you cannot create views; can you create packages?  If so perhaps you could move the code into a package and call it from Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you can use in Forms hasn't progressed in over a decade. 
Dynamic SQL is the best answer. I think you should look at [EXEC_SQL](http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-11899896.html)